# How to Filter Parsed XML data by Element Content [jQuery]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, xml-parsing

So I have a xml housing property feed [on a WordPress site] currently that is pretty simple, it just gathers the fields i want to show and displays that as a list [pretty normal stuff] But i now need to be able make two lists, one that shows only sold properties, and one does not show sold properties. Currently my code is as follows:

```
jQuery(function( $ ){

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/properties2.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: parseXml
    });
});

function parseXml(xml)
{
    $("#xmlmain").html("<div id='content' data-role='listview' data-inset='true'></div>");
    $(xml).find("property").each(function() {
        $("#content").append("<div class='xmlwrapper'><div class='xmlleft'><img src='"+$(this).find('[name="Photo 1"]').text()+"'/></div><div class='xmlright'><h2>"+$(this).find("advert_heading").text()+"</h2><p class='price'>"+$(this).find
        ("price_text").text()+"</p><p class='priority'>"+$(this).find("priority").text()+"</p><p>"+$(this).find("main_advert").text()+"</p><a href='"+$(this).find("web_link").text()+"' target='_blank'>VIEW > </a></div></div>");
    });
}
});
```

Im pretty novice at Javascript and Jquery so im really not sure how i go about filtering the lists to exclude sold and only include sold properties. How do i adapt/filter this to get the required result? I tried some attemps with filter(); function but it just kept stopping the feed from displaying at all.

This was the snippet/example i was trying to incorporate/work with:

```
var getTextNodesIn = function(el) {
return $(el).find(":not(iframe)").addBack().contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
    });
};

getTextNodesIn(el);
```

The data i need to use is in the Priority Field shown below. Here is an extract from the xml feed:

```
<properties>
<property reference="MR139">
    <instructedDate>06/08/2018 17:07:05</instructedDate>
    <price_text>£600,000</price_text>
    <numeric_price>600000.0000</numeric_price>

    <priority>On Market</priority>

    <advert_heading>house for sale</advert_heading>
    <main_advert>some text about the property</main_advert>
    <web_link>www.example.com</web_link>
    <property_style>Detached</property_style>
    <property_reference>111111</property_reference>
    <newHome>NO</newHome>
    <noChain>NO</noChain>
    <furnished>Unknown</furnished>
    <currency>GBP</currency>
    <featuredProperty>NO</featuredProperty>
    <pictures>
        <picture name="Photo 1" lastchanged="2018-08-06T15:44:48.5800534Z">
            <filename>example.jpg</filename>
        </picture>
    </pictures>
</property>
</properties>
```

[The text in the priority field for sold properties will either be "Sold" or "Sold STC" if that makes a difference.]

Any help would be much appreciated, even if its just pointing me to resources i can use that are relevant to my problem. My searches seem to turn up unrelated information, potentially due to me wording things wrong due to not knowing the terminology properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the value of `priority` in your `each` method using `startsWith` method like below.

```
$(xml).find("property").each(function() {
    var priority = $(this).find("priority").text();

    if(priority.startsWith('Sold')) {
        //for sold properties
    } else {
        //for unsold properties
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks so much for your answer, this has worked for me perfectly. I do have a single final question, can you have multiple startsWith entrys in the same command. for example > if(priority.startsWith('Sold', 'Sold STC')) { > or should i just create an additional step in the loop to do this? basically whats the better method?

Comment: Glad to help. You can use multiple `startsWith` like `if(priority.startsWith('Sold') || priority.startsWith( 'Sold STC')) {`. @Moose

Answer (score 2):

Good luck dude..   it seems the community dont use xml in real life. I ve researched for days now and cant get even get a straight answer to storing the xml in a database or using xquery to get the data i need from the .xml feed directly... to then find an answer on how a user could search by e.g. price and  display property in price order seems light years away it seems...

if your using wordpress it looks like property hive plugin might be your best bet... cost £150 but all searching is done for you.

Comment: Thanks man. Yeah its a pain in the arse thats for sure. Im gonna try and get enough rep on here to put a bounty on the question, not sure what else to do now at this stage! unfortunately i cant use a plugin as the guy the site is for already pays for a system that doesnt have a plugin i can install. Typical huh.

Comment: thought you said : "on a WordPress site" at start of question. Have you found how you save an xml feed to a relational dbase?  are you supposed to store the pictures for example of a property in a seperate table? if so this is a pain in ass to do with php insert queries becuase everything has to link to a property_id in another table i presume .

Comment: i did say on a wordpress site. It is on a wordpress site but the dude has an expertagent system and he wants the xml connection to the wordpress site. All data comes from the expertagent as their system also publishes to rightmove and similar other places. So he adds properties via their portal, then that publishes it to and xml feed that then i need to draw the info in from.

Comment: thats what property hive is for.   Agent-> creates property on Expert Agent -> xml feed -> property hive/wordpress  -> creates properties as posts -> displays on a page.

Comment: Property hive does try to be a crm but it has a property feed funtion as well . you dont have to buy the whole package ( i dont think) . https://wp-property-hive.com/addons/property-import/     (see the third div along 'property import' )    i think most web comapnies use this as easy. i wanted to dig a bit deeper and not use wordpress....     but cant get best practice tuts anywhere... if i was a dev on comeercial budget i would use this though.

Comment: Hi. i think it will work for you. Why not call expert agent and see what everyone else does. Let me know (for my own knowledge) .  At moment iam looking at xslt and xquery and also sorts of weird things  to spit out the xml content.

Answer (score 2):

Your filter function is not correct. The way you're using `this` is not the way it's used in JavaScript. That's a common error because in most Object Oriented programming languages, `this` means a different thing than in JS. Try this function instead –keep reading below for a better version of that snippet–:

```
var getTextNodesIn = function(el) {
return $(el).find(":not(iframe)").addBack().contents().filter(function(element) {
    return element.nodeType == 3;
    });
};

getTextNodesIn(el);
```

The problem is that `Array.filter()` receives a function as the argument. That function is then called for each element of the array, and the element is kept if the function returns `true`. The function receives the elements as arguments. When the function is being executed, `this` is a reference to the global scope (weird, I know).

Your problem there is that you're checking if the property named `nodeType` of your global scope is 3. That `nodeType` is most probably `undefined` and therefore not equal to 3, so all the elements are filtered from the array and you're left with an empty array.

More info about filter in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Apart from that, there are some things I recommend you to revisit from your code.

1. Switch to using JSON instead of XML if possible. JavaScript has a library to deal with JSON strings. As a matter of fact, JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation. You could just do `JSON.parse(data)`, and you get a JavaScript object that you can use right away. It's just sooo much nicer to work with JSON than XML in JavaScript
2. In JavaScript the double equal comparator is considered bad practice in most of the cases. It can give you unexpected results. For example `"3" == 3` is true. The String 3 and the number 3 are the same when compared with double equals. Most of the time you will want to use triple equals, that compare the value and type of the things being compared
3. There's a better way to write functions that return in the first statement using the arrow function, that is a language feature introduced in ES6. It also auto bind the `this` from the outer scope, but that's a story for another day
4. I'd recommend that you use more meaningful names than "el". From the context, it seems "product" could be a better choice, but I'll keep "el" in the examples for clarity.

You could write the same snippet like this:

```
const getTextNodesIn = el =>
  $(el)
  .find(":not(iframe)")
  .addBack()
  .contents()
  .filter(element => element.nodeType === 3)

getTextNodesIn(el);
```

In my opinion that's more readable and clearer

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer sir! Now ive got it working how i intend i will use your info to improve my current code! Much appreciated. if i could give the bounty to both answers i would.